# R ggplot labels on stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I have data that I need to put into a stack bar chart but when I add the labels of the counts some of the labels are above the category and some are under the category.  I tried modifying position arguments of the geom_text function to no avail.

Below is a reproducible example showing the labels for the 'Under' category seating  above that category and the labels of the 'Over' category seating inside the bar.

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(AgeGroup = sample(c(rep("Over",10),"Under"), 6000, replace = TRUE),
DueDate = sample( 
         seq( as.Date("2015-01-01"), 
              as.Date("2015-06-30"), by="1 month") ,  
         6000,replace = TRUE),
             stringsAsFactors = TRUE) %>%
group_by(AgeGroup,DueDate) %>%
  tally() %>% ungroup %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x=DueDate, y=n, fill = AgeGroup),stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(x=DueDate, y=n
            ,label = prettyNum(n,big.mark = ","))
        , vjust = 0,  size = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title="Where are the labels")
```

Below is the output chart.
[image]

Comment: Just to note: data derived using `sample` is not strictly reproducible unless you use `set.seed()` first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `n/2` as the `y` position for `geom_text()`, and it will always fall "inside" the bar:

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(AgeGroup = sample(c(rep("Over",10),"Under"), 6000, replace = TRUE),
           DueDate = sample( 
               seq( as.Date("2015-01-01"), 
                    as.Date("2015-06-30"), by="1 month") ,  
               6000,replace = TRUE),
           stringsAsFactors = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(AgeGroup,DueDate) %>%
    tally() %>% ungroup %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(x=DueDate, y=n, fill = AgeGroup),stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(aes(x=DueDate, y=n/2
                  ,label = prettyNum(n,big.mark = ","))
              , vjust = 0,  size = 2) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(title="Where are the labels")
```

[image]

EDIT: That quick solution will only work for your specific example. If you have more than two categories per bar, or if the values are more evenly distributed, it will not fly. i.e.:

```
set.seed(999)
data.frame(Direction = sample(rep(c("South", "West", "East", "North")), 6000, replace = TRUE),
           DueDate = sample( 
               seq( as.Date("2015-01-01"), 
                    as.Date("2015-06-30"), by="1 month") ,  
               6000,replace = TRUE),
           stringsAsFactors = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(Direction, DueDate) %>%
    tally() %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    arrange(desc(Direction)) %>% 
    group_by(DueDate) %>% 
    mutate(pos = cumsum(n) - n/2) %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(x=DueDate, y=n, fill = Direction),stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(aes(x=DueDate, y=pos, label = prettyNum(n,big.mark = ","))
              , vjust = 0,  size = 2) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(title="Where are the labels")
```

[image]

So here's a general solution, that adds a "position" column to the dataframe (`arrange(desc(Direction)) %>% group_by(DueDate) %>% mutate(pos = cumsum(n) - n/2)`), to use with `geom_text()` and place the labels exactly where they belong:

```
set.seed(999)
data.frame(Direction = sample(rep(c("South", "West", "East", "North")), 6000, replace = TRUE),
           DueDate = sample( 
               seq( as.Date("2015-01-01"), 
                    as.Date("2015-06-30"), by="1 month") ,  
               6000,replace = TRUE),
           stringsAsFactors = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(Direction, DueDate) %>%
    tally() %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    arrange(desc(Direction)) %>% 
    group_by(DueDate) %>% 
    mutate(pos = cumsum(n) - n/2) %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(x=DueDate, y=n, fill = Direction),stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(aes(x=DueDate, y=pos, label = prettyNum(n,big.mark = ","))
              , vjust = 0,  size = 2) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(title="Where are the labels")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
geom_text(aes(label = n), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)
```